# How to access unnamed "enum class" encapsulated inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, enums, c++11

```
class A {
  public: enum class { HELLO, WORLD };
};
```

Having known that, inside a `class`, declaring a simple `enum` (rather than `enum class`) is a better idea, because it's already typed with the `class` identification. But still above statement is a valid `C++0x` signature. Now how to access an unnamed `enum class` outside ?

```
int i = A::HELLO; // error: ‘HELLO’ is not a member of ‘A’
```

Comment: it just doesn't compile right from the unnamed enum class :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, that is not valid. The C++0x FDIS says (9.2p1)

> Except when used to declare friends (11.3) or to introduce the name of a member of a base class into a derived class (7.3.3), member-declarations declare members of the class, and each such member-declaration shall declare at least one member name of the class.

In your case, no enumerator name is introduced into the class' scope and no enumeration name is introduced either. So, no member name at all is introduced by that member-declaration.

EDIT: And actually, there's a more direct prohibition of the enumeration declaration. 7.2p2:

> The optional *identifier* shall not be omitted in the declaration of a scoped enumeration.

Comment: which means that we cannot have its object initialized in constructor. So such `enum` will be entirely disconnected to outer world, correct ?