# Anonymous enum classes

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

Is is possible to write a anonymous enum class and then comparing what it contains? Eg.

```
enum class { APPLE, BANANA } fruitType;
// ...
if (fruitType == fruitType::APPLE)
    // ...
```

Comment: `enum class` - Did you tag C++/C++0x correctly? You you meant C++/CLI ?

Comment: Yes, I meant C++0x. I personally got no idea what CLI is

Comment: Which compiler? `enum class` doesn't get compile in native C++ - it should be either `enum` or `class`.

Comment: Doesn't matter. What I'm asking about here is about the standard, not compiler support. If your using g++, did you remember -std=gnuc++0x or -std=stdc++0x?

Comment: @Ajay: `enum class` is in C++0x.

Comment: @DeadMG: Got it. I have been using VC10 only, which doesn't support all C++0x features. I need to download GCC too!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `fruitType` is a variable (despite Type in the name). You cannot use a variable name to access things about its type.

The idea with `enum class` is that the values are not visible outside the definition unless you prefix them with the type name. If the type doesn't have a name, this will be difficult!

Comment: I don't think you can use `decltype` before `::`, but I'm not totally sure. :-)

Comment: VC++ 2010 doesn't let you (MS recommends using the no-longer-standard `std::identity<>` metafunction as workaround), but the FDIS permits it.

Comment: Gcc lets you do: `typedef decltype(fruitType) ft_t; if (fruitType == ft_t::APPLE)`

Comment: @ildjarn yes no problem. `decltype` can be used in the place of a nested identifier. https://godbolt.org/z/DkjFTG

Comment: @v.oddou : Yeah, at the time, flaky compiler support made these things questionable, but in hindsight all of these answers are themselves pretty questionable. ;-]

Answer (score 1):

Not this way. `fruitType::APPLE` is incorrect, as `fruitType` is not the name of a namespace. However, if you simply write `fruitType == APPLE` (without prefixing `APPLE`), then it's fine.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I failed to notice that we're talking about C++0x enum class. This would only work with old C / C++03 style enums, not with enum class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this doesn't make sense. It breaks the whole idea of the enum class, which was introduced to solve some of the problems of the traditional enums (export of enumerators to the surrounding scope, implicit conversion to int, impossibility to specify the underlying type). If you declare an anonymous enum class, its enumerators are not accessible, since they cannot be qualified. So it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
enum class { APPLE, BANANA } fruitType;
if (fruitType == fruitType::APPLE)
```

But you can do this:

```
enum class FT { APPLE, BANANA } fruitType;
if (fruitType == FT::APPLE)
```

...which is probably just as easy.

---

Note, that you probably want to initialize it:

```
enum class FT { APPLE, BANANA } fruitType = FT::BANANA;
if (fruitType == FT::APPLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

But I agree that it would be nice to be able to do this. Sometimes the enum is already part of a sufficiently nested and limited scope and further qualification would be pure overkill, yet you would still like to prohibit conversion-to-int. So you have to make a trade-off: choose both features or neither.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is [possible](http://www.ideone.com/24Efq). But if it's anonymous then, it won't be accessible outside its whatever scope.

**Edit**: Your second part of the question is an error. You don't have to mention `fruitType::`. However even after removing it; compilation fails. Which depicts that, it's not usable.

So I am not sure about your second question. I had [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301575/how-to-access-unnamed-enum-class-encapsulated-inside-a-class) long back.